# Auto generating code-behind files from .aspx files

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a designer working on several pages in Dreamweaver.  The designer is creating .aspx files with the Page directive at the top.  These are getting shipped to me and I'm adding them to the Visual Studio ASP.NET WebForms Web Application Project.  The problem is that there's no code-behind file by default, and I'm trying to find a shortcut to have them autogenerated as if I've added a fresh page from Visual Studio.

Is anybody aware of a shortcut?

Thanks!

Comment: Ha! You should use MVC instead. :)

Answer (score 3):

Add the aspx to your project, then right click on it and select "Convert to Web Application"

Comment: Convert to Web Application exists on the project, not the aspx file, and it does not create the code-behind files.

Comment: @Mike C.: Interesting.  The option normally exists for the aspx files when the designer file isn't present.  Just tested it myself and apparently it also doesn't show when there is no codebehind.  Odd.  Anyway, I think Wyatt has the best answer (excluding the convert to MVC part).

Answer (score 1):

Long term, answer to working with designers is to upgrade to MVC. A little easier to work with.

For the task at hand, this workflow has worked out pretty good in the past:

1) Create new web form (aspx) with appropriate name.
2) copy/paste in designer's code (sans @Page directive)
3) pray and such

Or, add the page from visual studio. Then pave over it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use T4 for your needs.

[T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit) Code Generation - Best Kept Visual Studio Secret](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx)